# why this render in eevee goes white?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

hey let me know why this render goes white when i do final render by pressing f12 ?
anyone evert who can solve this matter in 2.81a ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from a picture, attach the file. Dont you have some hidden object in front of the camera which is visible in render?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up